# Unorderable Types Error when working in SublimeREPL

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I seem to be having a problem using sublimeREPL to run python code with user input in sublime text 2. I have a working piece of code that I can use in the command prompt that will not execute inside REPL. The error seems to be that REPL cannot handle the format of the input and assumes it is a string. My python is fairly limited so is there a way to make the REPL play nice with my code or do I need to specify the input?

Note: Casting tempInput as a int each time will work but is tedious.

The Code:

```
# Matthew P
# A program to calculate average grades

def avg(total, elements):
    return total / elements

tempInput = 0
runningTot = 0
numGrades = 0

print("\nEnter Grades (Negative Value to Escape): ")

while tempInput > -1:

    tempInput = input("-->")

    if tempInput > -1:
        runningTot = runningTot + tempInput
        numGrades = numGrades + 1


print("\nQuit Command Givem")
print("Average Grade: " + str(avg(runningTot,numGrades)))
print("Grade Sum: " + str(runningTot))
print("Number of Grades" + str(numGrades))
```

The Output from command prompt:

```
~\Documents\Python Scripts>userinput.py

Enter Grades (Negative Value to Escape):
-->99
-->98
-->97
-->96
-->95
-->-1

Quit Command Givem
Average Grade: 97
Grade Sum: 485
Number of Grades 5
```

and the error when running in sublimeREPL (I ran is using the ctrl+,,f command)

```
Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 18 2013, 21:18:40) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
Enter Grades (Negative Value to Escape): 
-->100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
>>>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with sublime or the REPL; it's just a basic Python 3 issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input()` returns a string, but you are comparing it against an integer:

```
tempInput = input("-->")

if tempInput > -1:
```

Use `int()` to make the comparison:

```
tempInput = int(input("-->"))
```

You ran the code on the command line *with Python 2*, where `input()` evaluates the entered string *as a Python expression*. Python 2 also doesn't mind you comparing numbers and strings; numbers *always* sort before numbers.

In Sublime, you ran the code under Python 3, however, where `input()` *only* takes string input.

Comment: Hmm, I am a bit confused. Wouldn't the 'print()' commands not run in command line if it was running python 2? Other than that your solution of casting the input makes it much simpler than the work around I thought of so thanks!

Comment: @Matt: Python 2 ignores the `(..)` as mere expression grouping. Had you tried to use the `print()` function with multiple arguments (e.g. `print("Average Grade:", avg(runningTot,numGrades))` Python 2 would have printed a *tuple*.